# ¿Como puedo resolver esta consulta?

Tags: sql, oracle

Me preguntan: ¿cuál es la placa del vehículo marca mazda mas caro vendido en el 2017?

Tengo 3 tablas: vehículo, propietario, venta

- Vehículo: placa primary key,color, marca,modelo
- Propietario: id primary key,cédula, nombre, apellido, correo.
- Venta: idven primary key,propietario, vehículo, precio,fecha

Hice esta sentencia pero no me da

```
Select placa from vehiculo Where marca='mazda' and (select max(precio) from venta);
```

¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Comment: Es bueno que des la información completa, me refiero a las relaciones de las tablas para tener una mejor claridad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No es necesario usar subconsultas en este caso, lo recomendable sería utilizar un `INNER JOIN` para unir los registros que se encuentran en las tablas `vehiculo` y `venta` usando la clave foránea `placa`.

En la condición (`WHERE`) hay que indicar tanto la marca como el año en que se hizo la venta (Ej: 2017), si la fecha tiene el formato `YYYY-MM-DD` se usa `YEAR()` para obtener solo el año.

Con la cláusula `ORDER BY` podes ordenar las ventas de forma descendente teniendo en cuenta el precio, es decir, de la más cara a la más barata y con `ROW_NUM` limitar la consulta para que solo te devuelva el primer registro (la venta más cara de todas).

```
SELECT placa
FROM vehiculo
INNER JOIN venta ON vehiculo.placa = venta.vehiculo
WHERE marca = "mazda" AND YEAR(fecha) = "2017"
ORDER BY precio DESC
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

---

### Normalización

Consiste en un proceso en el cual se aplican reglas sobre cada una de las tablas para evitar la redundancia de datos, disminuir problemas al actualizar los datos y para proteger la integridad referencial de los datos.

#### Reglas

- Uno o más vehículos van a tener el mismo modelo
- Uno o más modelos van a pertener a una marca
- Solo por dependencia transitiva un vehículo va a pertenecer a una marca, es decir, un vehículo por ser modelo `x` va a tener una marca `y`

`Vehículo > Modelo > Marca`

#### Problema

En tu tabla `vehiculo` las columnas `modelo` y `marca` van a tener redundancia de datos, lo que significa que se van a repetir en múltiples registros los mismos valores (*¡Eso es malo!*).

Los problemas que te podría ocasionar son:

- Ocupar más espacio en disco
- Dificulta las consultas `SQL` sobre todo si existen valores que no son idénticos (`masda` y `mazda`)

#### Solución

Se crean nuevas tablas para evitar la redundancia de los datos.

- Crear una tabla `marca` con las columnas `id_marca` y `nombre`
- Crear una tabla `modelo` con las columnas `id_modelo`, `nombre` y `id_marca` *(FK)*
- Modificar la tabla `vehiculo`, eliminado las columnas `marca` y `modelo` y agregando la clave foránea `id_modelo`

**¿Cómo quedaría la consulta SQL?**

Suponiendo que el `id_marca` 1 pertenece a la marca "Mazda".

```
SELECT placa
FROM vehiculo
INNER JOIN modelo ON vehiculo.id_modelo = modelo.id_modelo
INNER JOIN venta ON vehiculo.placa = venta.vehiculo
WHERE modelo.id_marca = 1 AND YEAR(venta.fecha) = "2017"
ORDER BY venta.precio DESC
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: como detalle, faltaria un AND en el where, donde dijera  **YEAR(fecha) = 2017**

Comment: @Jakala Gracias por avisar, también me di cuenta del detalle cuando volví a leer la pregunta.

Comment: excelente respuesta, matias

Answer (score 0):

```
Select veh.placa from vehiculo veh, 
      venta ven where veh.placa=ven.vehiculo and ven.precio >= 
      select max(precio) from venta venx , vehiculo vehx 
            where venx.vehiculo = vehx.placa and vehx.marca = 'mazda'
```

Comment: Hola ctm002, ¿podrías elaborar un poco más tu respuesta? Se marcó de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Si explicas qué hace tu consulta y como resuelve el problema planteado por el OP, sería mucho mejor.